# Accessing TM1 Cognos REST API through C# , when server hosted with Integrated mode 5 (CAMPassport)

Tags: c#, cognos-bi, cognos-tm1

I am trying to call the REST API exposed from IBM TM1 Cognos. Using the HttpWebRequest object. Getting the 401 when i tried to pass Authorization header with base64(user:password:namespaceId).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("username:password:camnamespace");
    var encodeData= System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "CAMNamespace "+ encodeData);

    //GET Method  
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://serveraddress/api/v1/Cubes");

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var det = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();        
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Internal server Error");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like in `payton: verify=False` to trust the certificate of response.